# NameError: global name 'ms' is not defined after running learning_tf start_demo.launch

Tags: ros, python, roslaunch, tutorial, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Running through the tf tutorials in sequence and currently at [tfTutorialsWriting a tf listener (Python)](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28Python%29).

Run roslaunch learning_tf start_demo.launch and get following errors:

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1432379077.642128] bad callback: <function handle_turtle_pose at 0x7fd1eb45d6e0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 709, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg, cb_args)
  File "/home/andrew/catkin_ws/src/learning_tf/nodes/turtle_tf_broadcaster.py", line 12, in handle_turtle_pose
    tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, ms.theta),
NameError: global name 'ms' is not defined
```

Can see the 2 turtles appearing in the window. Can move 1 turtle via arrow keys but 2nd turtle does not follow turtle 1

Note: have run apt-get update and lots of ROS packages updated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209814/nameerror:-global-name-%27ms%27-is-not-defined-after-running-learning_tf-start_demo.launch/) by [andrewwi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22489/andrewwi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you are missing a `g` in `msg` in your code.  [see the example](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28Python%29#CA-535ecf1b33de9267f08a855ee826b648436c3ded_12)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andrewwi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22489/andrewwi/) on 2015-05-24**:
Oops. Thanks .